# Open layers tracker doesn't update

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm building a simple ISS tracker with coordinates from the API using Open layers. The map and the point renders correctly, but I can't update the position of the point on the map without refreshing the page. I paste the code below.

```
import "ol/ol.css"
import Feature from "ol/Feature"
import Map from "ol/Map"
import Point from "ol/geom/Point"
import View from "ol/View"
import { Circle, Fill, Style } from "ol/style"
import { OSM, Vector as VectorSource } from "ol/source"
import { Tile, Vector } from "ol/layer"
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj"


const getISSPosition = () => {
    fetch("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            const ISSPosition = [data.longitude, data.latitude]
            const ISSPositionMercator = fromLonLat(ISSPosition)

            const map = new Map({
                layers: [
                    new Tile({
                        source: new OSM()
                    })
                ],
                target: "map",
                view: new View({
                    center: [ISSPositionMercator[0], ISSPositionMercator[1]],
                    zoom: 2
                })
            })

            const positionFeature = new Feature()

            positionFeature.setStyle(
                new Style({
                    image: new Circle({
                        radius: 4,
                        fill: new Fill({
                            color: "red"
                        })
                    })
                })
            )

            positionFeature.setGeometry(new Point(ISSPositionMercator))

            new Vector({
                map: map,
                source: new VectorSource({
                    features: [positionFeature]
                })
            })
        })
}

getISSPosition()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the call to the service from the construction of the map.  Construct the map once, then update the position of the marker periodically by calling the service with `setInterval`.

Create map:

```
const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
})

positionFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 4,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: "red"
      })
    })
  })
)

new ol.layer.Vector({
  map: map,
  source: new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
    features: [positionFeature]
  })
});
```

update marker:

```
const updateISSPosition = () => {
  fetch("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const ISSPosition = [data.longitude, data.latitude]
      const ISSPositionMercator = ol.proj.fromLonLat(ISSPosition);
      positionFeature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(ISSPositionMercator));
      map.getView().setCenter(ISSPositionMercator);
      console.log(ISSPositionMercator);
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w13ka0ot/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
const positionFeature = new ol.Feature();
const updateISSPosition = () => {
  fetch("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const ISSPosition = [data.longitude, data.latitude]
      const ISSPositionMercator = ol.proj.fromLonLat(ISSPosition);
      positionFeature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(ISSPositionMercator));
      map.getView().setCenter(ISSPositionMercator);
      console.log(ISSPositionMercator);
    });
}

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
})

positionFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 4,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: "red"
      })
    })
  })
)

new ol.layer.Vector({
  map: map,
  source: new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
    features: [positionFeature]
  })
});
updateISSPosition();
setInterval(updateISSPosition, 5000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<title>OpenLayers example</title>
<b>My Map</b>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```